# Remove parent node but keep child node htmlagility pack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Ok I'm stumped here how can I remove a parent node and replace it with its child?

My goal here is to remove outbound links from images. I do not want to remove normal links fromt he document just remove the ones making an image into a link while keeping the image intact. 
 Example:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com"><img src="logo_w3s.gif"></a>
```

Should be replaced and become:

```
<img src="logo_w3s.gif">
```

Here's my code that doesn't work but I feel is getting close:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(maintext);
dynamic allimages = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").ToList;

if (scrapeimages.Checked) {
    //the user does want images scraped. Remove image outbound links
    try {
        foreach (void n_loopVariable in allimages) {
            n = n_loopVariable;
            if (n.ParentNode.Name == "a") {
                dynamic outer = n.OuterHtml;
                dynamic newnode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(outer);

                n.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(n.ParentNode, newnode);

            }
        }
        maintext = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    } catch {
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw I used a converter to convert this from Vb.net to C# so if there's weird errors that probably why.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Comment: Hell yes it did. I would never have thought to do it that way. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(yourANode);
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node, true);
```

Something like this should help, this will remove Child of the parent node of your `<a>`, but it will keep grandChildren. This true parameter in `RemoveChild` indicates `keepGrandChild`.

If all `<img>` have `<a>`

```
var nodeList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("img");

for(HtmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    var parentATagNode = node.Parent.Parent;
    parentATagNode.RemoveChild(node.Parent, true);
}
```